# Prove that $\hspace{1mm} (\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\})/{]0, \infty[}\cong\mathbb{S}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations, group-isomorphism

I have been struggling to get a better grasp of the overall picture of what's going on throughout my solving process, perhaps, it's due a lack of a better understanding of some of the concepts involved such as fibers of an application as equivalence classes an orbits of a group action on a set also as equivalence classes and how do they relate to each other.

I was given an action of $]0, \infty[$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\}$ defined as $t\cdot x = tx$ where $t \in \hspace{0.5mm}]0, \infty[$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\}$, and an application

\begin{align*}
  \varphi\colon\hspace{0.5 mm}\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\} & \longrightarrow\mathbb{S}^n \\[0ex]
  x & \longmapsto \frac{x}{||x||}
\end{align*}

where $\mathbb{S}^n$ is the $n$-sphere. And I must prove the following: $$(\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\})/{]0, \infty[}\cong\mathbb{S}^n$$

My initial thoughts on this were to begin to prove that $\varphi$ is a group morphism, which is, because $\varphi(1)=\frac{1}{||1||}=1 \hspace{0.5mm}$ and $\varphi(xy)=\frac{xy}{||xy||}=\frac{x}{||x||}\cdot\frac{y}{||y||}=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)$. And then having in mind the

**First Isomorphism Theorem**,

finding the kernel of $\varphi$ and checking if $\varphi$ is an epimorphism so that $Im(\varphi)=\mathbb{S}^n$ in order to assure

$$(\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\})/{\ker\varphi}\cong\mathbb{S}^n$$

and hopefully having $\ker\varphi = ]0, \infty[$ but it turns out we have a monomorphism which means I can't use this line of thought. On the other hand I'm aware that we can define with the action operation with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\}$ as $$x\sim_{]0,\infty[}y\hspace{2mm} \text{if}\hspace{2mm} \exists\hspace{0.5mm}t\in \hspace{0.5mm}\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\}: y = t \cdot x $$

and that its equivalence classes $[x]_{\sim_{]0,\infty[}}$ are the orbits of each element of $]0, \infty[$, given by

$$Orb(x) = \{y \in\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\}\hspace{1mm}\colon\hspace{1mm}  y = tx\}$$
besides I believe we can define another equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\}$ as

$$x\sim_{\varphi} y \hspace{2.5mm}\text{if}\hspace{2.5mm} \varphi(x)=\varphi(y)$$
whose equivalence class of a particular element is a fiber of $\varphi$ given by $$[x]_{\sim_{\varphi}} = \varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x)) = \{y \in\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\}\hspace{1mm}\colon\hspace{1mm} \varphi(x)=\varphi(y) \Leftrightarrow \frac{x}{||x||} = \frac{y}{||y||}\} = \{y \in\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\}\hspace{1mm}\colon\hspace{1mm}y = x \cdot\frac{||y||}{||x||}\}$$ Let $t = \frac{||y||}{||x||}$ and we have that $Orb(x) = [x]_{\sim_{\varphi}}$

**Is this enough to conclude that $(\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\})/{]0, \infty[}\cong\mathbb{S}^n$?**

I believe I'm not getting a full grasp on this and can't explain why either... My professor is giving lectures we're not supposed to have in first place, this is an 2º year undergrad exercise and I'm not even that much into abstract algebra yet, so not everything seems intuitive at first sight.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Is this really supposed to be a **group isomorphism**?  What is the group operation for $\mathbb R^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$?  What is the group operation for $\mathbb S^n$?

Comment: I didn't have that information in the exercise sheet, but I believe from what I saw in classes for $\mathbb{S}^{n} $ it is the multiplication of complex numbers. Now I think you're right when it comes to $ \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus\{0\}$, I don't think it is supposed to be a group... Is the exercise still valid? This way we won't have a quotient group but a quocient set only.

Comment: Sorry, it can't be the complex multiplication, only if we were talking about $\mathbb{S}^1$. I'm not that into abstract algebra but I'm trying to study a lot about it in the fastest way possible to these class.

Comment: $S^n$ has a (sensible) group structure only when $n=0,1,3$.  This exercise must mean "homeomorphism."

Comment: As Gerald and Randall note, despite the group action here, this isn't about groups and homomorphisms, but about topology (open and closed sets) and bi-continuous mappings. <> The main ideas are: The orbits are rays from the origin, each is a closed set and intersects the sphere precisely once.